# mysql trigger when update or insert - update field in affected row/rows

Tags: mysql, function, triggers

I have table `new` which have columns `stock` and `delivery_days`.

I need when something updating/inserting rows when stock or delivery days has changed, trigger must update field `status` which can be recieved by calling function CheckStatus(stock, delivery_days) and return 0 or 1

I tried:

```
BEGIN
            IF NEW.stock != OLD.stock or NEW.delivery_days != OLD.delivery_days
            THEN 
            UPDATE new set status = CheckStatus(stock,delivery_days);
            END IF;
END
```

but it won't run because it will infinity cycling.

CheckStatus:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE `status` INT(11);

    IF stock >= 1 and ddays = 0 THEN SET `status` = 1;
    ELSE SET `status` = 0;
    END IF;

    RETURN `status`;
  END
```

fiddle example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tvGDajBRxUrHVvWjFnaiYu/0

Comment: show please the create table and some data. Also calling the table new is a bad idea. I would make a new table with a better name and make a new trigger anbd test it then.

Comment: added example at fiddle

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger (ie you cannot UPDATE new )

Comment: I understood, P.Salmon you are already answered me in another my question about this issue. Now im using `where CheckStatus(...)=?` but it works slow on big table, so I need real column with status and have index. I want to do this in poor sql because on client side somebody can forgot update `status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to change a column of the row being inserted/updated, don't use `UPDATE`, just use `SET NEW.status = ...` That will change the value only on the current row that spawned the trigger.

Also you must qualify the other columns as `NEW.stock` and `NEW.delivery_days`.

```
BEGIN
  IF NEW.stock != OLD.stock or NEW.delivery_days != OLD.delivery_days
  THEN 
    SET NEW.status = CheckStatus(NEW.stock, NEW.delivery_days);
  END IF;
END
```

I agree with the comment above that you shouldn't name your table `new`, or any other [SQL keyword or reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), because it will make your code confusing to anyone who reads it.